# How to programmatically show custom context menu onkeyup event in ckeditor 4.1.1 standard

Tags: ckeditor

I want to create and show custom context menu in ckeditor. (all context menu items will be custom not default like: cut, copy, paste, etc.).

Context menu show when onkeyup event occur, how its possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use because you need focus :

```
config.startupFocus = true;
```

And

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.focus();
```

Documentation : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-startupFocus